# Gettin only the Text and Image from a link

Tags: java, android, webview

As you see in the picture I have a WebView that I fill it with a Link got from News Websites.My question is that Is there a way to get the Text of this news and its Image only instead of getting the whole page? Because when the whole Web page is there it looks like a browser 
[Please take a look at my ScrenHot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECV2B.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the RSS feeds from news site like http://feeds.bbci.co.uk/news/rss.xml
 or use News API -> https://newsapi.org/ .If you are using RSS feeds you will get list of news items in xml format which you have to parse in order to get title ,subject and image from it . Nearly each newspaper have similar type of RSS feeds so you don't different technique for different newspaper . In case of News API , you can get similar feeds in json format . Choose whatever format you like .